# Telegram bot api python - выполенение функции каждые N минут

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Хотел бы узнать, как возможно реализовать вызов бота через какой-то промежуток времени.

Как я понял, библиотека telebot работает таким образом - Если приходит запрос, то выполняется функция, типа Callback. Сама по себе main() функция не будет вызываться если нет запроса от бота.

Но каким образом реализовать постоянную проверку времени. Меня интересует не сам метод проверки времени, а принцип. Понятное дело, что While true: или time.sleep() в данном контексте не сработает или же я ошибаюсь?

Запросы обрабатываю через @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

Answer (score 0):

Решил данную проблему потоками и cronjob'om

кому интересно, нижу решение.

```
import telebot
import schedule
import time
import threading

# Telegram variables
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

def cronTask():
    print("Я сработал")

def runBot():
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)

def runScheluders():
    schedule.every(1).minute.do(cronTask)

    # Start cron task after some time interval
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=runBot)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=runScheluders)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Comment: Exorsky а можно весь код данного решения? > У меня вообще задача такая: Есть БД SQL, из нее нужно каждые 30 минут
> выводить температуру, если она превышает 23 градуса. Вывод нужен в
> телеграмм-бот. Может есть похожая задача или просто подскажите механизм вывода сообщений телеграмм-ботом через заданный интервал времени?